# validate Google recaptcha in react login application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recaptcha

I have a react application in which I use a google Recaptcha in the Login component. I don't want users to log in without checking the "I'm not a robot" Recaptcha. I am using a state but I am not as successful as the state never changes, how can I do? I have the code below.

```
export default class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        captcha: false,
    }

}

callBack = () => {
    console.log("something inside re captcha");
}

verifyBack = (response) => {
    if (response) {
        this.setState({
            captcha: true,
        });
    }
}

onSubmit = () => {

    //  checking if captcha state is true to log in but not successful. 
    // log in only after checking the I'm not a robot box (assuming username/password matches).
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required />

                <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required />

                <button type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Login </button>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember" /> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
            </div>
            <div className="row invisible-recaptch">
                <ReCAPTCHA
                    sitekey="6Lf8zsgUAAAAAHV1_VcrNDHfWuYAXw1tUSLnexQg"
                    render="explicit"
                    onloadCallback={this.callBack}
                    verifyCallback={this.verifyBack}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}}
```

Comment: is verifyBack function  being triggered ?

Comment: no, verifyBack is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, 
I think you need to bind your `verifyBack` function in constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     ...

   this.verifyBack = this.verifyBack.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: It is bound, sorry that I didn't add that line here. My constructor has this.verifyBack = this.verifyBack.bind(this);

Comment: can you mention the library you are using for captcha ?

Comment: npm react- recaptcha library

Comment: there is issue in this libary check this : https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha/issues/228

Answer (score -2):

- Your problem will solve.Inside verifyBack function u do not have
  access of this so that setState is not working.bind the function with
  this will help u to do this.